# Automapper and inheritence

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a following structure

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastUpdDt { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastUpdUs { get; set; }
}
public abstract class BaseDictionary : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
public abstract class BaseDictionaryCouncil : BaseDictionary
{
    public virtual int CouncilId { get; set; }

    //FK
    public virtual Council Council { get; set; }
}
public class Animal : BaseDictionaryCouncil {}
```

Council  entity is like:

```
public class Council : BaseEntity
{
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    //Navigation
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

So `Animal` is my DAO. I have also DTO's with the same structure but called `[NameEntity]Entity` (AnimalEntity). Then I'm trying to map it using Automapper:

```
var entities = Repository.Get();
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Animal, AnimalEntity>();
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var entitiesModel = mapper.Map<List<Animal>, List<AnimalEntity>>(entities.ToList());
```

but in the last line I got this a huge error:

[image: error image]

Please help me, what i'm doing wrong. Let me know if I have to add more informations. Thanks

**UPDATE**

I notice that if I commented out here then work fine but I cant do that:

```
public abstract class BaseDictionaryCouncil : BaseDictionary
{
    public virtual int CouncilId { get; set; }

    //FK
    //public virtual Council Council { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your `Repository.Get()` method is failing when it is actually being executed in the `ToList()` call. "LastUpdUs" is an invalid column name; it's not actually AutoMapper.

Comment: I saw some entity framework errors in there:  `Invalid column name: LastUpdUs`

Comment: I also think so, but it is not. Repository.Get() returns all columns with information. EF query is `SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[CouncilId] AS [CouncilId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[LastUpdDt] AS [LastUpdDt], 
    [Extent1].[LastUpdUs] AS [LastUpdUs]
    FROM [dbo].[Animal] AS [Extent1]` and it returns proper info

Comment: @KumarJ. add the `.ToList()` call to your first line, so it reads as `Repository.Get().ToList()`. See if that causes an error on that line.

Comment: @WillRay I did it. Everything is OK. I can show you screen in debug mode

Comment: @WillRay please look https://s17.postimg.org/gpgi6nerz/temp.png

Comment: @ps2goat https://s17.postimg.org/gpgi6nerz/temp.png

Comment: are you still getting errors? if so, update your question with the new info.

Comment: Of course yes! Do you see any solution?